# android sqlite query with multiple where

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using sqlite in android where i am fetching result by passing multiple where clause, which gives me an error.
Single where clause works fine for me problem is with multiple where clause.
suggest me the changes or identify the mistake I am doing please

Error message with query

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(837): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: 
no such column: Maharashtra:,while compiling: SELECT _id, r_shop FROM retailer 
WHERE r_state = Maharashtra AND r_city = Thane AND r_region = Checknaka

String selection = MySQLiteHelper.STATE + " = Maharashtra"  
                +" AND " + MySQLiteHelper.CITY + " = Thane"
                +" AND " + MySQLiteHelper.REGION + " = Checknaka";

        Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.RETAILER_TABLE, 
                    new String[] {MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID, MySQLiteHelper.SHOP }, selection, 
                    null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
String selection = MySQLiteHelper.STATE + " = 'Maharashtra'"  
            +" AND " + MySQLiteHelper.CITY + " = 'Thane'"
            +" AND " + MySQLiteHelper.REGION + " = 'Checknaka'";

    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.RETAILER_TABLE, 
                new String[] {MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID, MySQLiteHelper.SHOP }, selection, 
                null, null, null, null);
```

May be the reason is that, you are refering to Strings without `''`

Comment: _Nunu I have 1 more problem that is The string that i am passing in where clause should also ignore the case sensitivity. what should i do for that

Comment: thanks, and check this: http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.it/2012/04/android-sqlite-ignore-case-from.html

Comment: That was useful for raw query what if i am not using raw query

Comment: then try: http://itsgreatupnorth.blogspot.it/2011/10/ignoring-case-in-sqlite-android-queries.html